# Table CSS is not showing up at all

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this simple html code. I am simply trying to format the colors but none of the CSS is actually formatting it.

I've tried changing the variables names, changing the table class to id and vice-versa.

```
<head>
    <style>
    .cool-table {
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: blue;
        color: purple;
    }

    .cool-table tr:first-child td {
        font-size: 30px;
        background-color: red;
        color: green;
    }

    #cell-style {
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <table class="cool-table">
            <tr>
                <th id="cell-style">Fruit</th>
                <th id="cell-style">Price</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th id="cell-style">Apples</th>
                <th id="cell-style">$10</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th id="cell-style">Banana</th>
                <th id="cell-style">$50</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th id="cell-style">Mango</th>
                <th id="cell-style">$20</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should show the entire table background as blue and the text should be purple. The first row's text should be large with a red background and green text. The rest of the cells should have a blue background with purple text and size 8px font.

Comment: you need to wrap the table in a `<body>` element.. and your `<style>` in a `<head>` element, **inside** the `<html>` tag before `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your header cells to `th` and the normal cells to `td`. That way you do not need a id, class or `tr:first-child` to separate the header row from the rest. Note that if you use `id`, you should only use it on a single HTML tag. For multiple tags use `class` instead.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .cool-table {
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      background-color: blue;
      color: purple;
    }
    
    .cool-table th { /* Changed to th, no need for tr:first-child */
      font-size: 30px;
      background-color: red;
      color: green;
    }
    
    .cool-table td { /* Styling td-tags (table cells) */
      font-size: 8px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="cool-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Fruit</th> <!-- Keep as th -->
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Apples</td> <!-- Changed to td -->
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>$50</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>$20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it this way :

```css
.cool-table {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: blue;
  color: purple;
}

.cool-table tr:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  color: green !important;
}

.cool-table tr:not(:first-child) {
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="cool-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Fruit</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Apples</th>
    <th>$10</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Banana</th>
    <th>$50</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Mango</th>
    <th>$20</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first-child has a red background and green color, and everything that is NOT the first child gets a font-size of 8 and is aligned to the left.

Comment: Thank you but what about styling each cell? I don't do that?

Comment: @Marshall for your specific problem you don't need to, and even if you wanted to style each cell you should use a `class` and not an id, cuz `id`'s are unique and shouldn't be used in multiple places. You're welcome happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues to look at.

1. `style` tag belongs in `head` tag which belongs in the `html` tag.
2. You can't use multiple `id`s in the same document - [they're supposed to be unique](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/). Try using a `class` like below.
3. the second css block doesn't do anything. Maybe you want to remove the `td` from the selector like below?
4. Several of your styles are not being applied because they override each other. Try making the selectors more specific to give them higher precedence.

You really want to understand the [structure of html documents](https://html.com/document/). You can verify them using the [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

You can also learn more about [CSS from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html><head>
    
      <style>
          
      .cool-table {
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: blue;
        color: purple;
    }
    
    .cool-table tr:first-child { /* removed 'td' */
        font-size: 30px;
        background-color: red;
        color: green;
    }
    
    .cell-style { /* changed to class */
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        color: yellow;
    }
    
      </style>
      </head><body>
    
        <table class="cool-table">
            <tr>
                <th class="cell-style">Fruit</th>
                <th class="cell-style">Price</th>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <th class="cell-style">Apples</th>
                <th class="cell-style">$10</th>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <th class="cell-style">Banana</th>
                <th class="cell-style">$50</th>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <th class="cell-style">Mango</th>
                <th class="cell-style">$20</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```